# C#/ASP.NET: can't remove cookies with Domain property specified

Tags: c#, cookies, subdomain

I have the following code in my login method:

```
Response.Cookies["cookie"].Value = "...";
Response.Cookies["cookie"].Domain = "domain.com";
```

This way the cookie is put into the main domain and all subdomains

However when I try to remove the cookies:

```
Response.Cookies["cookie"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
```

It doesn't work!

When I remove the 2 line of code where Domain property is specified, it works fine.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone? I've been struggling with this for ever....

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Okay, I figured that out.

When you remove a cookie with Domain property set, you need to set the very same property for the new fake cookie:

```
if (Request.Cookies["cookie"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("cookie");
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
    myCookie.Domain = "domain.com"; // !!!!
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

Comment: You sir saved my day!!

Comment: SAVED MY LIFE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you are setting `Expires` while the `Response` is on a subdomain...
Crosscheck: Can you try and set it from the domain itself and see if that works ?

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195%28v=VS.100%29.aspx you can delete a cookie by:

```
if (Request.Cookies["cookie"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("cookie");
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I set the cookies from the domain itself. I tried the very same example, and it works only in Opera.

Comment: Thanks for providing proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

Need to set domain and value with empty string. It does not work without value.

```
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName, string.Empty)
        {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1),
            Domain = {YourDomain}
        };

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested in `.Net 5`

```
        foreach (var cookie in HttpContext.Request.Cookies)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie.Key, new CookieOptions()
            {
                Domain = Request.Host.Host // ADD
            });
        }
```

response header example

> set-cookie: _example=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; domain=YOUR.DOMAIN; path=/

`CookieOptions()` are optional and could be omitted, but then cookies in response will not have the domain name set.

Answer (score 0):

Searched around quite a bit and couldn't get it to work. 
I had to actually set the value property to make it work! Using mvc 3 .net 4.

```
        var current = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key];
        if (current == null) return;
        var myCookie = new HttpCookie(key)
                           {
                               Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1),
                               Value = current.Value,
                               Domain = domain
                           };
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(myCookie);
```